# Windows CE MessageBox not displaying unicode text and Icon Transparency

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, windows-ce

I am modifying a Windows CE application to display various languages via Unicode.

By changing the font on the resource file I managed to get the displayed in a button but cannot get it to display "παρίσταταί" correctly in a MessageBox.

The result looks like this:

[image: Should show "παρίσταταί"]

I found a open source [XMessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox) replacement and got it working in Windows CE with some minor changes. The result is this:

[image: What happened to the icon background?]

My problem is due to not being able to set the font via a Message Box Hook (not available in Win CE) I set the font to "Arial Unicode MS" in XMessageBox and the text will be displayed BUT the icon is not correct.

How do I get the MessageBox to use another font **OR** how do I get XMessageBox to not have a transparent ICON background?

The desktop version of [XMessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox) can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox) and I have [GitHub](https://github.com/davidgwright/UnicodeTest) repo of the test program for you to look at the code - in the CUnicodeTestDlg::OnInitDialog method.

```
    CStringW greekText( L"παρίσταταί" );

    TheButton.SetWindowText( greekText  );

    ::MessageBox(*this, 
            greekText,
            L"Is this greek?", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONHAND );

    XMessageBox( *this, 
            greekText,
            L"Is this greek?", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONHAND );
```

**Please note:** "Arial Unicode MS" needs to be installed on the Device or Emulator for the XMessageBox to display the Greek text correctly.

Comment: I can't see an error in GitHub code, it's probably something weird about Windows CE. Why don't you just remove the icon? Those icons are huge, it takes about 1 MB for 4 icons. Also double check that "Arial Uniocde MS" is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by getting a device with the corresponding non-english operating system installed on it (Which was Japanese and used Japanese text - not Greek). This way the text gets displayed correctly and the buttons on the MessageBox are in the appropriate language. I removed the use of XMessageBox and leave the standard Windows API one in use.